# Encountered an error when attempting to require('sails);

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sails.js

i am having a terrible day figuring out this error. Below is Dockerfile and docker-compose. I addded 'RUN npm -g install sails', error persist Encounter an error when attempting to require('sails') [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMfWA.png)

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:latest

ARG NODE_ENV=development
ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV PORT=80

RUN npm config set unsafe-perm tru
RUN npm install -g sails mocha waterline && npm cache verify
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install -g @sailshq/lodash


WORKDIR /src
COPY src/package*.json ./
RUN npm i npm@latest -g

  
RUN npm install
COPY src/ .
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "npm run start:$NODE_ENV" ]
```

```
  admin-backend:
    image: 630239505623.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ssn-admin-backend:d05cbcb
    build:
      context: ../ssn-admin-backend
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_admin_backend"
    environment:
       NODE_ENV: development
       PORT: 80
       sails_datastores__default__adapter: 'sails-mysql'
       sails_datastores__default__url: 'mysql://ssn-admin:ssn-admin@mariadb:3306/ssn-admin'
       sails_datastores__default__host: 'mariadb'
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=admin-backend'
      - 'traefik.port=80'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.admin.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'
    volumes:
      - ../ssn-admin-backend/src:/src
```

Comment: What's the error?  Can you [edit] the question to remove the link to the image, and replace it with the actual text of the error?  I see a potential problem in that the `volumes:` are hiding everything that's in the Dockerfile, including its `node_modules` directory; does deleting the final `volumes:` block in the `docker-compose.yml` file help?

Comment: Deleting volumes in docker-compose.yml, gives new error.            
 
ssn_admin_backend |   error: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'ssn-admin'@'172.25.0.8' (using password: YES)